# "home?status=" Twitter share URL not working anymore?

Tags: twitter, twitter-share

We've just found out that the `/home?status=` version of sharing URL does not work anymore, I'm pretty sure it did a while back. When did this happen? I'm unable to find any changelogs or publications about this.

**Old, does not work anymore:** 
https://twitter.com/home?status=Foo+bar

**New(?) version:**
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=foo+bar

Comment: It *may* have worked, but this URL has never been a documented way to post a Tweet, and the Tweet intent has been the correct and documented way to do this for at least the past ~6 years.